# nodemailer sending empty files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I have written a script to send email with an attachment from an form but the mail is sending empty attachments rather than the original document and upon trying to access path iam getting the following error:-

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read errno: -4068, code: 'ESTREAM', syscall: 'read', command: 'API'

Here is my code :-

```
app.post('/apply',(req,res)=>{
    const output=`<p>You have new Job Application</p>
     <h3>Contact & Position Details</h3>
     <ul>
      <li>${req.body.email}</li>
      <li>${req.body.name}</li>
      <li>${req.body.phone}</li>
      <li>${req.body.position}</li>
     </ul>`;
      console.log(path.dirname(req.body.resume));
      var file =req.body.resume;
     let transporter=nodemailer.createTransport({
         service:'gmail',
         auth:{
             user:'<email>',
             pass:'<password>'
         },
         tls:{
             rejectUnauthorized:false
         }
     });
     let mailOptions={
         from:'"Resume for review" <atul.11192@gmail.com>',
         to:'atul.11192@gmail.com',
         subject:'Job Application',
         text:'Hi ! I have applied at datadock',
         html:output,
         attachments:[{
             filename:file,
             path:path.dirname(file)
         }]

     };
     transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,(error,info)=>{
         if(error)
         {
             return console.log(error);
         }
        res.render('final.ejs',{message:'Email has been sent'}); 
     });
});
```

can anyone tell me how i can solve this problem ? i'm open to use another library

Comment: First of all you need a valid file in order to attach it to the email. Do you upload the files before this and sending the file name in `req.body.resume`? Because the way you are doing it, you expect that `path.dirname(file)` is a path to an existing file on the server and `filename:file` will be the name of the attachment in the email. If attachment `path` is not a valid path to a file that's why you get empty attachment ...

Comment: @codtex i got the error so how can i get the path of the file from the system it has been uploaded?

Comment: You can use `formData` on the front end to submit everything - user input + files to upload (_research on how you should do it_) and then you need to handle `formData` on the server side. For example take a look on [**formidable**](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) module. Then once you handle your `formData` you would know where the file is and u can attach it to the email